# Task Manager, Registry Editor, Control Panel, Group Policy Editor Dark Mode

Tags: themes, windows-10-v1909

Is it possible to have the Task Manager, Registry Editor, Control Panel, Group Policy Editor and other such applications which are not in dark mode to be in the dark mode even when the default app theme is set to Dark.

Currently on Windows v1909.

Comment: Dark Mode doesn't currently work on anything other than Windows UWP apps, Windows Explorer and Settings. There were rumors of a system-wide Dark Mode with the next 2005 Update, but I suspect it won't be there either. Reason is, regular x86 / x64 Windows applications don't support a Dark Mode theme in the dwm.exe process.

Comment: @Didier Let’s see if we get the dark theme in 2005 update, I am in the fast ring of windows insiders program as well to know if it is released.

Comment: It would be consistent with Microsoft's desire to offer a full-dark-mode-theme experience to end-users, but there are more technical considerations to factor in than just a new set of colors. When dwm.exe was introduced in Vista, it was supposed to make a better use of a growing breed of new GPUs that allowed to draw vectorially, instead of composing windows the way it was done in XP and before. The sad truth is, it works, it's stable, but not very sexy nor really scalable, because MS didn't really pursue in this direction. The generalization of large-screen monitors is partly to blame.

Comment: @Didier Kudos to the developers working hard.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft are adding dark modes across their apps slowly but surely, but this doesn't include most of the older programs.  Just as a tip, when I want a dark mode task manager, I hit Win + G to get the windows game bar, and from their you can access a limited task manager panel.  Definitely doesn't have all the options, but it's nice to have as an overlay when doing heavy work.

Comment: ^ Correction: It's Windows Key + G